# Search for 'Proper case' and mark it invalid using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-cleaning

I have a big data set with multiple columns in it. Data Frame example is below, Here column 'first' holds names which I want to check whether is Proper case or not ? like **aamir** should be **Aamir** and **Aamir malik** should be **Aamir Malik**.

[image: Input Data Frame]

I want something like below.

[image: Reuired Output]

I used Pyspark and below codes where I am getting the right answer but I want to detect it first and then make changes.

Here I have add a new column 'correct' and performed function.
`name_check_1 = name_check.withColumn("correct", initcap(col("first")))`

Then compare columns correct and first so it gives me not proper case name.
`name_check_2 = name_check_1.filter('correct != first')`

I need a way to get not proper case first and then correction.

Comment: Your question doesn't make logical sense..  because, "We cannot 'detect' an invalid entry without comparing the entry with a correct value, so logically you have to first form the 'correct' field then only you can get the flag, there is no other way"

Answer (score 2):

My solution below :

Logic : Slice the string for first alphabet check it with correct string if equal it is valid else invalid. Make uppercase the first alphabet of firstname and lastname and rest to lower case and concatenate. Select only relevant columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
values = [
(1,"aamir"),
(2,"Aamir"),
(3,"atif"),
(4,"Atif"),
(5,"tahir"),
(6,"sameer"),
(7,"ifzaan"),
(8,"Ifzaan"),
(9,"Saquib"),
(10,"aamir malik"),
(11,"adcA")


]
rdd = sc.parallelize(values)
schema = StructType([
    StructField("IDs", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("first", StringType(), True)
])
#create dataframe 
data = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

#split first column into firstname and lastname
data = data.withColumn("firstname", split(data["first"]," ")[0]).withColumn("lastname", split(data["first"]," ")[1])

data = data \
        .withColumn("flag", when((trim(substring(data["firstname"],0,1)) == upper(trim(substring(data["firstname"],0,1)))) | 
                    (trim(substring(data["lastname"],0,1)) == upper(trim(substring(data["lastname"],0,1)))), lit("valid")).otherwise(lit("invalid"))) \
        .withColumn("correct" , concat(concat(upper(trim(substring(data["firstname"],0,1))), trim(lower(substring(data["firstname"],2,1000)))),lit(" "),
                                       when(data["lastname"].isNull(),lit("")) \
        .otherwise(concat(upper(trim(substring(data["lastname"],0,1))),trim(lower(substring(data["lastname"],2,1000))))))) \
        .select("IDs","first","flag","correct")

data.show()
#Result

+---+-----------+-------+-----------+
|IDs|      first|   flag|    correct|
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+
|  1|      aamir|invalid|     Aamir |
|  2|      Aamir|  valid|     Aamir |
|  3|       atif|invalid|      Atif |
|  4|       Atif|  valid|      Atif |
|  5|      tahir|invalid|     Tahir |
|  6|     sameer|invalid|    Sameer |
|  7|     ifzaan|invalid|    Ifzaan |
|  8|     Ifzaan|  valid|    Ifzaan |
|  9|     Saquib|  valid|    Saquib |
| 10|aamir malik|invalid|Aamir Malik|
| 11|       adcA|invalid|      Adca |
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi Manish , Thank you for your answer, I am it with my data in meantime can you please add some comments in your codes so understand it properly.

Comment: brother using your code **adcA** output is **AdcA** which is not proper case even **aamir malik** is showing **Aamir malik**

Comment: I will fix it for surname, code was only written for firstname. Could you explain more how adcA's output should be, i mean what is the proper case for it.

Comment: **Adca** means every word should have first capital letter and other is small and if a person has space in the name then after space again capital letter and others are small

Comment: I have updated the solution and comments as well. Please accept it as answer if it works for you.

Comment: this a much longer and inefficient approach. correct approach should be to use inbuilt function of initcap.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.initcap

Comment: @aamirmalik124, "We cannot 'detect' an invalid entry without comparing the entry with a correct value, so logically you have to first form the 'correct' field then only you can get the flag, there is no other way"

Comment: @RemisHaroon, Yes I did the same way earlier ..I was want to know whether there is any other better method.

Answer (score 2):

You know how to use `initcap`, so just create new column `correct` and compare it to the column `first` to check if it's already valid or not:

```
df.withColumn("correct", initcap(lower(col("first")))) \
  .withColumn("flag", when(col("correct") != col("first"), lit("invalid")).otherwise("valid")) \
  .show()
```

Gives:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-------+
| id|      first|    correct|   flag|
+---+-----------+-----------+-------+
|  1|      aamir|      Aamir|invalid|
|  2|      Aamir|      Aamir|  valid|
|  3|       atif|       Atif|invalid|
|  4|       Atif|       Atif|  valid|
|  5|      tahir|      Tahir|invalid|
|  6|     sameer|     Sameer|invalid|
|  7|     ifzaan|     Ifzaan|invalid|
|  8|Ifzaan Abcd|Ifzaan Abcd|  valid|
|  9|Saquib abcd|Saquib Abcd|invalid|
+---+-----------+-----------+-------+
```